# smarty getcwd() variable in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I have to check for file_exists in smarty (prestashop) but I can't find a way to get base directory of prestashop.

Is there any way I can return php's getcwd() with smarty? Another good solution is if you can tell me if there is a prestashop reserved variable?

`{$base_dir}` returns http://... (url) but I need /home/user/public_html

Is it defined somewhere in smarty's reserved variables?

Comment: set varible `$bas`e with `getcwd()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP constant with smarty:

```
{if file_exists($smarty.const._PS_ROOT_DIR_|cat:"/path/to/file.jpg")}
   {* code *}
{/if}
```